# Implementation for backing up folders/files to remote dest via ssh with hourly backup schedule and backup prior to system shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

Please suggest backup implementation that meets the following requirements:

- Allows me to specify folders/files to backup
- Stores the backup on a remote destination via ssh
- Compresses the backup
- Allows scheduling hourly backup + backup prior to system shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you want to do. There are many ways to do backups, from plain file copies using `scp` to much more sophisticated solutions. If you want to permanently keep the backups, I heartily recommend [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) which you can find out about if you google `bup backup`.

This solves the "stores backup on remote destination via ssh" and "compresses the backup".

Whatever program you end up using, you can [use cron to schedule hourly backups](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=use+cron+to+schedule+hourly+backups).

In addition the question on how to run a command on shutdown with Ubuntu [has already been answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83473/how-to-execute-script-on-shutdown).

Comment: I have wrote a simple bash script, in which `scp` is used. I will look into `bup`. Thanks.